# Como resolver erro em makemigrations (Django)

Tags: python-3.x, django

Estou tentando executar o comando `python manage.py makemigrations`, e está gerando esse retorno no meu terminal, até mesmo quando eu tento dar início no server Django usando o `python manage.py runserver`, o terminal me retorna o mesmo erro.

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\rhama\Documents\GitHub\Django> python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rhama\Documents\GitHub\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "c:\users\rhama\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.db.backends.postgressql'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rhama\Documents\GitHub\Django\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\rhama\Documents\GitHub\Django\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\rhama\Documents\GitHub\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line        
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\rhama\Documents\GitHub\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\rhama\Documents\GitHub\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\rhama\Documents\GitHub\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\rhama\Documents\GitHub\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "c:\users\rhama\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\rhama\Documents\GitHub\Django\receitas\models.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Receita(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\rhama\Documents\GitHub\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 122, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\rhama\Documents\GitHub\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 326, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\rhama\Documents\GitHub\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 207, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\rhama\Documents\GitHub\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
  File "C:\Users\rhama\Documents\GitHub\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "C:\Users\rhama\Documents\GitHub\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 204, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\rhama\Documents\GitHub\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 122, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.backends.postgressql' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

Todo esse erro começou depois que eu inseri uma classe no meu arquivo **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime


class Receita(models.Model):
    nome_receita = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ingredientes = models.TextField()
    modo_preparo = models.TextField()
    tempo_preparo = models.IntegerField()
    rendimento = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    categoria = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_receita = models.DateField(default = datetime.now, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Creio que não esteja acostumado com o log (ou stacktrace). Na última linha do erro, é mostrado o erro principal e possíveis soluções.

Basicamente você definiu a ENGINE de forma equivocada, às vezes acontece. Em vez de *django.db.backends.postgressql* deveria ser *django.db.backends.postgresql*. Por falta de atenção ou dedo pesado, acrescentou um "s" a mais.

Eu geralmente utilizo o *django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2*.

Para ver as configs na documentação: [documantacao#engine](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#engine) e [pg_notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes).

Espero ter ajudado!